# LINQ SqlQuery<T> with random number of fields selected

Tags: c#, sql, linq, runtime

I am making a run time sql query and getting data from database using LINQ **SqlQuery<>**

```
SchoolSoulLibrary.SchoolSoulDataEntities ss = new SchoolSoulLibrary.SchoolSoulDataEntities();
string query1;
    var li = ss.Database.SqlQuery<MasterBank>(query1).ToList();
```

where MasterBank class is

```
public Partial class MasterBank
{
        public MasterBank()
        {

        }
        public decimal BankId { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> UserId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SchoolId { get; set; }
}
```

if i am executing this query

```
query1 = "Select * from MasterBank"; or
query1 = "Select BankId,BankName,UserId ,SchoolId  from MasterBank";
```

Its not giving any error and returning all data

but if i am executing this query

```
query1 = "Select BankName,SchoolId  from MasterBank";
```

error occured 
i understand the reason of this error that it return a result of the type of class MasterBank but what can i do now because query1 is generating runtime with random no of properties of class MasterBank.
is there any other alternative of doing it rather than **SqlQuery<>**

kindly suggest

Comment: BankId is not nullable, so if the query doesn't fetch BankId then you get the error!? Can you make BankId nullable?

Comment: @erikH, it looks like a bank identifier so I doubt it could be nullable.  If this is the case, I worry that it is a `decimal` and not an `Int32` or `Int64` (or even a `Guid`).

Comment: @Moo-Juice, Since you don't always fetch the bank id it is not required. Could it be a way to create a TempMasterBank class that has BankId as nullable, along with the other properties. Then the query would always work and you can then convert to the MasterBank class. It is up to your convert code to decide how to create an MasterBank instance if BankId is not known.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, Or you could adjust the query to always fetch BankId!?

Answer (score 2):

All the fields that are optional need to be marked as optional (nullable) in MasterBank class.

This one shouldn't cause any problems:

```
query1 = "Select BankId ,SchoolId  from MasterBank";
```

So the quickest fix is just to make all your fields nullable.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

My original answer was way off...

I think you will need the type you use to match the result you expect. So define a new type to match your query:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public string BankName {get;set;}
    public int SchoolId {get;set;}
}

SchoolSoulLibrary.SchoolSoulDataEntities ss = new SchoolSoulLibrary.SchoolSoulDataEntities();
string query1;
    var li = ss.Database.SqlQuery<SomeClass>(query1).ToList();
```

If you don't know until runtime what fields you will return - consider using a dataset instead of entity framework or try something like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206416/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-4-1-SqlQuery