# C# unable to create class having Nullable<string>

Tags: c#, .net, class, nullable

I am new to c# and please correct me wherever i am wrong
I am trying to make a class having Nullable property but it gives error on building the class my class looks like

```
public class vwAcdAdmissionWithvwAcdAdmissionSessionDetailWithAllMaster1
    {
        public Nullable<string> Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> StudentNameWithLedgerName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AASDid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> StudentLedgerId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> LedgerName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SessionId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> ScholarNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ClassId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SectionId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> MediumId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> StreamId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> HouseId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> FeeCategoryId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SchemeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> RollNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SchoolId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> UserId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ShiftId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> StreamName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> ClassName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> HouseName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> SectionName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> ShiftName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> MediumName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> FeeCategoryName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<string> DiscountType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Discount { get; set; }
}
```

error is Error  is 
 **`The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'`**
i did not understand what it mean and what i can do now
please suggest me and thanks for your valuable feedbacks

the reason why i want to make my string nullable is similar to my pervious post
[last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952912/linq-sqlqueryt-with-random-number-of-fields-selected/19953159?noredirect=1#19953159) 
it gives error when it return non nullable string

Comment: That's a huge classname :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string` is already a *nullable* type, because it's a class. You can use `Nullable<T>` only with `struct`s.

Looking at the source code of `Nullable<T>`:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

`string` definitely does not fulfill the generic constraint here.

Comment: +1, but you don't need to go to the source code. [MSDN is clear enough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b3h38hb0.aspx).

Comment: @Co.Aden What's unclear about this answer? Strings are nullable already, and in fact there is no such thing as a non-nullable string in C#. So just declare your string properties as regular strings, but you can leave the decimal properties as `Nullable<decimal>`.

Comment: yes i understand this that string is nothing like nullable string

Answer (score 3):

Message says what it means: *only* structures (value types) can be used in `Nullable<T>`.

Since `string` (or `System.String`) is a [Reference Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) - and is most certainly not a structure which is the cause of the compiler error! - then *expressions of such a (reference) type inherently allow `null` as a value* and there is no need to wrap them with `Nullable`.

To "fix" this, simply change all `Nullable<string> x` to `string x`.

Comment: i edited my post please tell me what should i do now

Comment: @Co.Aden Not sure what changed. *All* `Nullable<string>` should be replaced so that it even compiles. If there are additional problems (not related to this compiler error) then make sure to create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

string is a refrence type and for to be used in Nullable T must be a value type.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.90).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Anyways you can do `string s = null` so there is no need for `Nullable<string>`

Answer (score 2):

Many correct answers here already, but since the OP still seems a little confused, I'd like to make this point as simple and clear as possible:

You should use `Nullable<something>` with a `something` that can not, on it's own, have a value of `Null`. Take `DateTime` for example - it has a default value of `DateTime.MinValue` (a constant representing 01.01.01), but can *never* have a value of `Null`. The same goes for `int`; it can never hold a value of `null`

Ie, you can't do:

```
DateTime invalidDate = null;
```

But you CAN do:

```
Nullable<DateTime> validDate = null;
```

**String, on the other hand, *can be null*, so you basically *don't need* Nullable:**

```
string justFine = null;
```

Trying to use `Nullable<string>` therefore makes little sense, and that is basically what you need to know to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`decimal` is a ValueType. `string` is a Class. Null cannot be assigned to variables that are ValueTypes unless you wrap them in `Nullable<>`. Null can already be assigned to variables that are classes like `string`.